# avoid of send null from destroyed activity to restarted service

Tags: java, android

I want to programing app for data track in background , so I use service . 
I want to write a program that monitors all data sent and received by the device, and when the total volume of received or received messages reaches a specified value, the Internet device is turned off.

So I used the following code to monitor the data:

```
mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes ();
mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes ();
```

And I used the services to work on the background in the background.

To specify the download or upload limit from the user with edittext, I requested this limit in mainactivity and send this value to the service.

The problem is when: When I destroy the program, I will restart the service and get the NULL value and the program crashes.

My application code:

Main Activity :

```
package ir.alexandre9009.service;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.TrafficStats;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public static long UPP;
public static long DLL;
    Button startService,stopService;
    public Context context=this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (FirstService.mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED || FirstService.mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
            alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
            alert.show();
        } else {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
        startService=(Button)findViewById(R.id.startService);
        stopService=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stopService);

        startService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText UP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UP);
                String UPPP = UP.getText().toString();
                UPP=Long.parseLong(UPPP);

                EditText DL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DL);
                String DLLL = DL.getText().toString();
                DLL=Long.parseLong(DLLL);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstService.class);
                String myString = DLLL;
                intent.putExtra("StringName", myString);
                startService(intent);
            }

        });

        stopService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),FirstService.class));
            }
        });
    }
    public final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView RX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RX);
            TextView TX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TX);
            RX.setText(Long.toString(FirstService.rxBytes));
            TX.setText(Long.toString(FirstService.txBytes));
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
    };
}
```

Service :

```
package ir.alexandre9009.service;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.TrafficStats;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstService extends Service{
    public static long mStartRX ;
    public static long mStartTX ;
    public static long rxBytes ;
    public static long txBytes ;
    public long dl=MainActivity.DLL;
    Context context=this;
    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            rxBytes = (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX)/1048576;
            txBytes = (TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX)/1048576;
            if (rxBytes==2) {
                stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),FirstService.class));
                Intent i = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(i);

                //  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
               // wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
//معرفی توست برای نمایش یک پیام کوتاه به کاربر در هنگام خاموش کردن وای فای
                Toast.makeText(FirstService.this, "هشدار", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
    };
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(this,"staart",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mStartTX=0;
        mStartRX=0;
        mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

        return Service.START_STICKY;


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        TrafficStats.clearThreadStatsTag();
        Toast.makeText(this,"FirstService Stoped",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mStartTX=0;
        mStartRX=0;
        super.onDestroy();
    }



}
```

AndroidManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.alexandre9009.service">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".FirstService"

            >

        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please help me ...

Comment: Please help ...

Comment: Please provide better code. Provide at least a stacktrace

Comment: @BardyaMomeni  
سوال دقیقم توی آخرین پست نوشتم : 

http://p30droid.com/topic/6911-%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%AD%D8%AC%D9%85-%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AA%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%84%DB%8C-%D9%88-%D8%AF%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%AA%DB%8C-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%AA/?do=findComment&comment=26861

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line

public long dl=MainActivity.DLL;

You're referring to a variable in the Activity, surly when the Activity is destroyed, this variable is no longer in scope, thus you get Null Exception.

You must get this value using the intent.

The other problem is that you can't prevent any service from being killed by the system except foreground services which need to show a notification to the user. But this is not suitable for your situation.

Therefore, the best approach for you is to check whether intent is null or not. If it is not null, you get the value and save it into Preferences or Database or somewhere, if it is null, you retrieve the value from where you stored it before.